# python garbage collector does not remove tf.keras models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, garbage-collection

There is a class in which I store the tf.keras model

After instantiating the class, I call the method to update the model.

Why does the amount of memory consumed increase each time update () is called? It feels like the garbage collector is not removing the old model

code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from memory_profiler import memory_usage


class CustomModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        input_x = layers.Input((64, 300), name='fasttext_output')
        lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256))(input_x)

        dense_neurons = []
        for i in range(30):
            x = layers.Dense(64, name='intent_{}_layer_1'.format(i))(lstm)
            x = layers.Dense(1, name='intent_{}_layer_2'.format(i), activation='sigmoid')(x)
            dense_neurons.append(x)

        out = layers.Concatenate()(dense_neurons)
        out = layers.Reshape([30])(out)

        model = Model(inputs=[input_x], outputs=[out])
        return model

    def update(self):
        self.model = self.create_model()


custom_model = CustomModel()

custom_model.update()
print(memory_usage())
custom_model.update()
print(memory_usage())
custom_model.update()
print(memory_usage())
custom_model.update()
print(memory_usage())
```

outputs:

```
[313.734375]
[335.171875]
[356.9765625]
[378.9921875]
```

P.S.
A similar situation is observed when tracking memory consumed through the resource monitor (mac os catalina) and htop (ubuntu 18) - I mean the problem is not related to the memory_profiler module

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `memory_usage`?

Comment: @SoumikRakshit here is the link to the given library: github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler however, I want to highlight that the problem has nothing to do with the use of this library - I observe the same memory behavior through the task manager / htop-command even without importing and using memory_usage-library